# How can I use MUMU emulator to android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

I need to use Mumu player emulator in android studio. I forgot how to paste mumu players adb,xe files into android studio SDK platorm. If you know about it, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a bat file in your SDK folder, which contain adb.exe with following text

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:7555
```

create its shortcut on desktop and run it.

Comment: where to write this ? in cmd or terminal? please tell me

Comment: Just Press the windows key and type cmd and run it with administrator privileges and paste  "adb connect 127.0.0.1:7555" and press enter. Mumu player will be displayed in Running Devices in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

lick File > Settings > Tools > Emulator (or Android Studio > Preferences > Tools > Emulator on macOS), then select Launch in a tool window and click OK.
If the Emulator window didn't automatically appear, open it by clicking View > Tool Windows > Emulator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).